# Opencart Multistore Different price for same products

Tags: opencart

I have a opencart website and three different stores. I want to add different price for same products for multiple store.

Comment: Please show, what you have already and which is minimal but relevant to help answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have used opencart for my website. I have add different stores from opencart admin, add products to each store. My question is how to add different price for same products from opencart admin

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set the default customer group for each store to something unique.  Then you can set a product "Special" that only applies to each customer group on a per product basis.  The only disadvantage here would be that your "special" prices would likely show as a discount (with red strike through price on the primary price).

If you'd only like to display the special price (per store pricing in this case) as regular price you could make a slight modification to your theme to work around the way it displays prices.

Answer (score 0):

You will follow the steps to create multi store in your website

http://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-do-opencart-multi-stores-work/

Above documentation will help you to create multi store

Good Luck